# why this doesn't activate?

Tags: database, visual-studio, connection-string

[image]

when I'm going to create ADO.NET Entity Data model and after selected a database its show this 2 radio buttons deactivated. How to activate those radio buttons?

Comment: There's no sensitive data?

Comment: I guess by storing some "sensitive data (for example, a password)" in the connection string

Comment: I mean seriously... the answer is in the screenshot... is this question really "how can I read words?"

Comment: @musefan "Me fail English? That's unpossible!" - Ralph Wiggum

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any sensitive data in the connection string so there's no point asking about it. In some cases you might store the username and password in there, that's when the fields would be enabled.

For example, this would enable the fields as it contains the User ID and Password fields that could give any outsider an access to your server:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: thank you for your help.i logged with my SQL authentication..now works fine .